# Issue loading Office Add-In in desktop versions of Outlook

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I have been working on building an office add-in for outlook mail. The add in works great on the online version of outlook and it also works great on mobile phones within the Outlook mobile app. I don't see any reason it wouldn't work the same in desktop versions of Outlook 2016. I have referenced several sample XML files to make sure I'm not missing anything.

At one point, I was getting an error saying "Office.js has not been fully loaded yet," but now I can't even debug it.

Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
           xsi:type="MailApp">
    <Id>{Id}</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Sample Add In</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Outlook Add In"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="This app helps you work more efficiently from your email inbox."/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="logo url"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="logo url"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="support url" />
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
        <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="source code"/>
            <RequestedHeight>350</RequestedHeight>
        </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs"
            ItemType="Message"
            FormType="Read"/>
    </Rule>
    <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

                    <!-- Message read form -->
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                        <!-- Task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="groupLabel" />
                                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                            <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                            </Action>
                        </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>


                </DesktopFormFactor>

            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>

            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="blue-icon-32" DefaultValue="icon" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="source code" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="label" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="long description" />
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>

        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

                    <!-- Message read form -->
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                        <!-- Task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="groupLabel" />
                                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                            <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                            </Action>
                        </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>


                </DesktopFormFactor>
                <MobileFormFactor>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                        <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                                <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="blue-icon-32" />

                                <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="blue-icon-32" />

                                <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                                <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                            </Action>
                        </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </MobileFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>

        <Resources>

            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="blue-icon-32" DefaultValue="icon" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="source code" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="label" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="long description" />
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

I have come across some other questions related to the above error, but answers are either missing or not working. I have tried adding `import 'core-js/client/shim';` to my `polyfills.ts` but that broke the application completely.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Edit:**

Here is what my `main.ts` file looks like:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

declare let Office: any;

Office.initialize = (reason: any) => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must Office.initialize always be set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603710/must-office-initialize-always-be-set)

Comment: So it is loading, just not fully loading with the javascript error in the console?  If so, can you post your JS?

Comment: @NickCaruso It appears that it does not get very far at all. It does not even get to the point where I can see the loader in my app-root tag (~first thing rendered in Angular application). The application is made up of several decently sized components, but I will post my main.ts file in the post above. I can't even see the console anymore because nothing happens when I try to open the debugger in Outlook.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov I don't believe it is a duplicate, but thank you for the reference.

Comment: The manifest looks correct.  However, we are unable to reproduce this issue without the link to the source code.  Could you either provide the source code to us or a simple repro of the issue?  Additionally, could you provide a screenshot of the error you are seeing?